# Jboss not reading jar files from server lib

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I am a bit lost at the moment in trying to determine why JBOSS is not picking up my jar files located in the server lib directory.  I have checked the jboss-service.xml and it is configured to fetch jars from the server lib directory.k  I am getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.  I have verified the class in question is indeed in the jar file and it is located in the server lib directory.

I am trying to get Compiere working on Ubuntu 11.10.  Compiere runs an older version of JBoss (4.2.3.GA)  I would have to assume it some configuration I have missed as others are running this application.

Comment: Which class is not found? Please copy the stack trace.

Comment: double check permissions on the jar file. Make sure the account that runs jboss has access.

Comment: It is a Compiere class - located in the server/compiere/lib directory.  I can see in the boot.log file that it is loading the file or appears to be loading it.

Comment: I have done a chmod 775 on all directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of things that caused the issue.  The first one was how JBoss was binding to the IP address when started.  I change the binding to -b 0.0.0.0 and this addressed issues with ports.  The next was to remove an exploded ear folder from the deploy directory since there was un-exploded already present by the same name.  Also it turned out that there were two jars by the same name but different classes, so removed the older one.  And now all is right in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Application servers usually provide some way to debug class loading information in order to make diagnostics of this kind of problem. I know how to do it in Oracle iAS, but I don't have experience with JBoss. I suggest you to [check this documentation from JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/LinkageErrors___Making_Sure_You_Are_Who_You_Say_You_Are-Debugging_Class_Loading_Issues.html)